# How to get properly indented XML on Android?

Tags: android, xml, indentation

Based on several examples here on StackOverflow I have the following code for indenting XML.
I have a source xml file in a `String`. Output however is not indented, but it also doesn't give any errors. Output is checked in the debugger, and doesn't contain any characters like spaces or tabs, that could be rendered wrongly and thus overlooked.

```
String input = "xmldata";
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
return stringWriter.toString();
```

I have also tried setting `indent-amount` to `"2"`, but then the app would complain about a unknown attribute. Probably this is not implemented in Android.

Am I doing something wrong here? Are there other options for generating a indented xml file from a source xml string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String input = "xmldata";
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(input));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
System.out.println(prettyPrint(doc));

public static final String prettyPrint(Node xml) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(stringWriter);

    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    tf.transform(new DOMSource(xml), out);
    return out.getWriter().toString();
}
```

Comment: I tried that one too indeed. It didn't work for me. I now solved the problem by writing my own formatter for XML Nodes.